# Texture widgets render OpenGL example

Tags: android, opengl-es, flutter

My Flutter app needs to display 3d model and allow user to rotate it. I implemented this via native views (ViewController & Activity) and C++ code for rendering, as next step I tried [Texture](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html) widget to remove native views and use only Flutter. I managed to display OpenGL rendering on iOS via [FlutterTexture](https://docs.flutter.io/objcdoc/Protocols/FlutterTextureRegistry.html), but don't understand how to implement on Android. Could you show any examples how to use OpenGL with [SurfaceTexture](https://docs.flutter.io/javadoc/io/flutter/view/TextureRegistry.html) and connect it to Texture widget?

Comment: It's not quite a full OpenGL example, but one of Flutter's integration tests includes the use of SurfaceTexture: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f407871cb908a3e18e1e03f15a9172982e710786/dev/integration_tests/external_ui/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/externalui/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SurfaceTexture should be passed to `eglCreateWindowSurface`, while OpenGL stack is being configured.

I spent a while and built example project and article:
https://github.com/mogol/opengl_texture_widget_example
https://medium.com/@germansaprykin/opengl-with-texture-widget-f919743d25d9

```
private void initGL() {
    egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
    eglDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    int[] version = new int[2];
    egl.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version);

    EGLConfig eglConfig = chooseEglConfig();
    eglContext = createContext(egl, eglDisplay, eglConfig);

    eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, texture, null);

    egl.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);
}
```

Comment: I successfully built an example based on yours. It worked, but I'm sturggling in rendering to the texture with glTexImage2D. Could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531692/how-to-render-opengl-in-flutter-for-android