# How to render OpenGL in Flutter for Android?

Tags: java, android, flutter, opengl-es

```
if (call.method.equals("createVideoRenderer")) {
            TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry entry = textures.createSurfaceTexture();
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = entry.surfaceTexture();
            this.surfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
```

This is my java method call that creates my `SurfaceTexture` and saves it into my class instance. I've been reading about SurfaceTexture's class and this is how I understand it:

I need to call `surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener listener)` to pass an instance of `SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener` that defines the function `onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)`. If I understood correctly, this function is called by `updateTexImage()`. So I think `onFrameAvailable` is supposed to grab the image and render it? If so, how can I call OpenGL functions inside it? Where's the OpenGL context?

I'm totally lost on how to render it. All Android OpenGL examples that I find use surface views or something like that. I need to know how to create a pure opengl context.

I also think that when onFrameAvailable is called, the surfaceTexture's texture is bound to the OpenGL context, so I don't need to create shaders, tune texture parameters, etc. I just need to render to it, perhaps calling `glTexImage2D`.

**So how to render something as simple as a red square with `glTexImage2D` using this SurfaceTexture that Flutter gives me?**

**UPDATE:**

I found this: https://github.com/mogol/opengl_texture_widget_example

and I successfully rendered a color by using

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0f, green, 0f, 1f);

GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

However, I want to use `glTeximage2D`. I tried simply adding

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 100, 100,
                0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

But it didn't work

**UPDATE:**

I did some research and discovered (I think) that android uses gl external textures, so I tried:

```
    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i = i+=4) {
        buffer.put((byte)255);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < bufferSize-1; i = i+=4) {
        buffer.put((byte)0);
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < bufferSize-2; i = i+=4) {
        buffer.put((byte)0);
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < bufferSize-3; i = i+4) {
        buffer.put((byte)255);
    }
   buffer.rewind();
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GLES11Ext.GL_RGB8_OES, 100, 100, 0, GLES11Ext.GL_RGB8_OES, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

I should see a red image, but I see nothing.

I also tries using `GLES20.RGBA8` in `glTexImage2D` but it didn't work. I also tried `GLES11Ext.glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES( GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, buffer )` in place of `glTexImage2D` and it also didn't work.

Comment: you can try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_opengl_view

Answer (score 0):

On the Android side, call `id()` method on instance of `TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry`, to get texture id.
On flutter side, use `Texture` widget. This widget accepts textureId as a param.