# How to implement Glium's Backend for Android's SurfaceTexture (Render with Rust into SurfaceTexture)

Tags: android, rust, opengl-es, egl, glium

Rust's [glium](https://github.com/glium/glium) lib is a nice OpenGL wrapper that facilitate slots of stuff. In order to implement a new backend for it, you must implement https://github.com/glium/glium/blob/cacb970c8ed2e45a6f98d12bd7fcc03748b0e122/src/backend/mod.rs#L36

I want to implement Android's SurfaceTexture as a `Backend`

Looks like I need to implement a new Backend for SurfaceTexture: https://github.com/glium/glium/blob/master/src/backend/mod.rs#L36

Here are the C++ functions of SurfaceTexture https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/surface-texture#summary

I think that `Backend::make_current(&self);` maps to [ASurfaceTexture_attachToGLContext](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/surface-texture#group___surface_texture_1ga0a204415e7f93b6b2a09cd4d71d3bb39)([ASurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/surface-texture#group___surface_texture_1ga5c6696f8d5335d9b71fbeff5f8265c7c) *st, uint32_t texName)

and `Backend::is_current(&self) -> bool` can be simulated somehow based on each `SurfaceTexture` being marked as active or not when this is called.

Maybe `Backend::get_framebuffer_dimensions(&self) -> (u32, u32)` is the size of the SurfaceTexture which is defined at creation so I can use that. I just don't know what to do with `Backend::swap_buffers(&self) -> Result<(), SwapBuffersError>`

and maybe `Backend::unsafe fn get_proc_address(&self, symbol: &str) -> *const c_void` can call some Android API that gets the address of the OpenGL functions

However, `ASurfaceTexture_updateTexImage(ASurfaceTexture *st)` looks important and needed, and I don't know what to map it to in the `Backend`. Also, what about `ASurfaceTexture_detachFromGLContext(ASurfaceTexture *st)`?

*PS: I know there are other ways to render to an android widget, but I need to render to a Flutter widget, and the only way it through a SurfaceTexture*

Comment: @kmdreko I have to use SurfaceTexture because that's what Flutter supports for rendering to an arbitrary Flutter widget.

Comment: @kmdreko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531692/how-to-render-opengl-in-flutter-for-android

Comment: thanks for the context, you should add that to the post itself so others understand the end goal

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this work some time ago, with a hack-ish solution, maybe it still works, because `glium` is not changing very much lately.

But in my experience using `ASurfaceTexture` yields unreliable results, maybe that is because I used it wrongly, or maybe because Android manufacturers do not pay too much attention to it, I don't know. But I didn't see any real program using it, so I decided to use the well tested Java `GLSurfaceView` instead and a bit of JNI to connect everything.

```java
class MyGLView extends GLSurfaceView
                implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public MyGLView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0);
        setRenderer(this);
    }
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLJNILib.init();
    }
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLJNILib.resize(width, height);
    }
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLJNILib.render();
}
```

Being `com.example.myapp.GLJNILib` the JNI binding to the Rust native library, where the magic happens. The interface is quite straightforward:

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

public class GLJNILib {

     static {
        System.loadLibrary("myrustlib");
     }

     public static native void init();
     public static native void resize(int width, int height);
     public static native void step();
}
```

Now, this Rust library can be designed in several ways. In my particular projects, since it was a simple game with a single full-screen view, I just created the `glium` context and store it in a global variable. More sophisticated programs could store the `Backend` into a Java object, but that complicates the lifetimes and I didn't need it.

```rust
struct Data {
    dsp: Rc<glium::backend::Context>,
    size: (u32, u32),
}

static mut DATA: Option<Data> = None;
```

But first we have to implement the trait `glium::backend::Backend`, which happens to be surprisingly easy, if we assume that every time one of the Rust functions is called the proper GL context is always current:

```rust
struct Backend;

extern "C" {
    fn eglGetProcAddress(procname: *const c_char) -> *const c_void;
}

unsafe impl glium::backend::Backend for Backend {
    fn swap_buffers(&self) -> Result<(), glium::SwapBuffersError> {
        Ok(())
    }
    unsafe fn get_proc_address(&self, symbol: &str) -> *const c_void {
        let cs = CString::new(symbol).unwrap();
        let ptr = eglGetProcAddress(cs.as_ptr());
        ptr
    }
    fn get_framebuffer_dimensions(&self) -> (u32, u32) {
        let data = unsafe { &DATA.as_ref().unwrap() };
        data.size
    }
    fn is_current(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
    unsafe fn make_current(&self) {
    }
}
```

And now we can implement the JNI `init` function:

```
use jni::{
    JNIEnv,
    objects::{JClass, JObject},
    sys::{jint}
};

#[no_mangle]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub extern "system"
fn Java_com_example_myapp_GLJNILib_init(_env: JNIEnv, _class: JClass) { log_panic(|| {
    unsafe {
        DATA = None
    };

    let backend = Backend;
    let dsp = unsafe { glium::backend::Context::new(backend, false, Default::default()).unwrap() };
    // Use dsp to create additional GL objects: programs, textures, buffers...
    // and store them inside `DATA` or another global.
    unsafe {
        DATA = Some(Data {
            dsp,
            size: (256, 256), //dummy size
        });
    }
}
```

The size will be updated when the size of the view changes (not that `glium` uses that value so much):

```rust
#[no_mangle]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub extern "system"
fn Java_com_example_myapp_GLJNILib_resize(_env: JNIEnv, _class: JClass, width: jint, height: jint) {
    let data = unsafe { &mut DATA.as_mut().unwrap() };
    data.size = (width as u32, height as u32);
}
```

And similarly the `render` function:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub extern "system"
fn Java_com_example_myapp_GLJNILib_render(_env: JNIEnv, _class: JClass) {
    let data = unsafe { &mut DATA.as_ref().unwrap() };
    let dsp = &data.dsp;

    let mut target = glium::Frame::new(dsp.clone(), dsp.get_framebuffer_dimensions());
    
    // use dsp and target at will, such as:
    target.clear_color(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    let (width, height) = target.get_dimensions();
    //...

    target.finish().unwrap();
}
```

Note that `target.finish()` is still needed although `glium` is not actually doing the swap.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I have to use SurfaceTexture because that's what Flutter supports for rendering to an arbitrary Flutter widget. Also, I'm gonna make a PR with any modifications for glium if needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531692/how-to-render-opengl-in-flutter-for-android

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry but I know nothing about Flutter. Anyway if you manage to make it work with raw OpenGL, I think that my trick to build a `glium` context should work just fine.

Comment: Do you have any idea on what do I do with `swapBuffers` and `make_current`? Maybe `make_current` is `SurfaceTexture`'s `attachToGlContext`, but there's no map to detach. Should I detach the old one when doing `make_current` for a new one? What about SurfaceTexture's `updateTexImage`? Looks important

Comment: Could you post your code for the SurfaceTexture? I'm trying to open a PR to add this funcitonatiliy. I tried here glueing attachToGlContext to make_current but I get ` attachToContext: invalid current EGLDisplay` and then `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 8548 (rfacetexturepoc), pid 8548 (rfacetexturepoc)`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have that code around. My target was to render to the screen, I tried a lot of things and only kept the one that worked: `GLSurfaceView`.